# Как сериализовать два объекта

Tags: c#, сериализация

Как сериализовать два объекта (Контейнеры)? Пример

```
class FirstContainer{
   List<First> = new First();
}

class SecondContainer{
   List<Second> = new Second();
}
class First{
   string str;

   public First(string s){
     str = s;
   }
}
class Second{
   First F; // Не должна потеряться ссылка!

   public Second(First f){
      F = f;
   }
}
```

Как правильно сериализовать два объекта что бы не потерялась ссылка на First?

P.S. Классы наведены для примера

Comment: `BinaryFormatter` сохраняет ссылки. Если устраивает двоичная сериализация и не нужен обмен данными с другими платформами.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov Да устраивает, но как осуществить?

Comment: Что бы связь оставалась?

Comment: А вы какую сериализацию имеете в виду? Бинарную? XML? JSON?

Comment: Имхо, вы себе усложняете жизнь, для сериализации просто создайте себе DTO-классы, а потом просто собирайте из них свои объекты вручную

Answer (score 0):

Если вас устраивает бинарная сериализация, то можно использовать класс [`BinaryFormatter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter(v=vs.110).aspx).

Ваш огрызок код даже не компилируется, но, допустим, ошибки исправлены и всё с ним в порядке. Создайте класс-оболочку для ваших двух объектов:

```
[Serializable]
class Wrapper
{
    public FirstContainer con1 = new FirstContainer();
    public SecondContainer con2 = new SecondContainer();
}
```

Он обязательно должен быть помечен атрибутом `Serializable`, так же как и все остальные ваши классы.

Код (де)сериализации элементарен:

```
var wrapper = new Wrapper();

var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

using (var stream = new FileStream("test.bin", FileMode.Create))
{
    formatter.Serialize(stream, wrapper);
}

using (var stream = new FileStream("test.bin", FileMode.Open))
{
    wrapper = (Wrapper)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
}
```

Недостаток этого подхода в том, что не получится обмениваться таким образом данными с другими платформами, кроме .NET.